# springdoc openapi UI unresponsive, when large response is returned by the API

Tags: springdoc-openapi-ui

We have recently migrated from springfox to springdoc openapi 3. One of the API returns around 2MB of data and it works normally in springfox but springdoc openapi UI is unresponsive for few minutes and it takes more than 2 minutes to render as well. Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable the syntax highlighter as detailed in https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/877